# How can I use this for loop variable in django?

Tags: django

CODE:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" style="width: 96px">
        {% for i in 150 %} <!-- here is what I ask for -->
            <option>{{ i + 1989 }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to make year select form which is from 1900 to 2050.

How can I use `i` variable in django template tag?

Comment: Create list of range and return from view, not directly within template.

Comment: @AnupYadav Is it impossible to make it on template tags?

Comment: Template tags is also good option but to have clean code for business logic I would suggest use in View. Do you need it for Addition? like `{{ i + 1989 }}`

Comment: Business logic means all data and further manipulation like *selection while edit* is useful if you keep that in VIEW file. Nothing much, this way you can avoid creating duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Template range loop](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1899/) from django

**syntax**

```
{% range start:step:end as i %}
     {{ i }}
{% endrange %}
```

**Example**

```
{% range 1900:1:2050 as i %}
     {{ i }}
{% endrange %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much easier solution using django template language filter.

views.py

```py
def my_view(request)
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'my_range':range(150)})
```

my_template.html

```
{% for i in my_range %}
  {{ i|add:1990 }}
{% endfor %}
```